# The type 'Nullable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, dll, nuget-package

I created a Class Library and NuGet package in order to share code to access our API.  (This is my first time trying any of this).  The Class Library was created using .NetStandard.  I used the "Pack" feature in Visual Studio 2019 to create the NuGet package.  I have installed the package in a new blank application to test.  It seemed to all work well until I tried to use the models in a view. I first tried it in a Telerik grid:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<iCANMVCSDK.Entities.Employee>()
    .Name("employeeGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.EmployeeCompanyId);
    })
)
```

I immediately received the error:

*"The type 'Nullable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.    1_Views_Home_Index.cshtml"*

I then just tried putting the model directly on the view:

```
@using iCANMVCSDK;
@model IEnumerable<iCANMVCSDK.Entities.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

I receive the same error.  I did add .NetStandard to the project, but I still get the same error.  I am assuming there is something I need to do in the Class Library before I pack it, but I do not know what.

This is what my Class Library project looks like.  I'm not sure what anyone needs to see in order to help me.

[image]

Here is project XML:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <Authors>Rani Radcliff</Authors>
    <Company>iCan</Company>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Description>The client library that enables sharing and retrieving data with iCan Web Api</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" Version="1.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net472" Version="1.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You'll have to do this without the Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies packages.  The NETStandard.Library package must be the only one that provides the BCL types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why, by I had to manually add a reference to the netstandard library in the web.config file of the MVC application:

```
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
      <assemblies>
          <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"/>
      </assemblies>
  </compilation>
```